# VNC doesn't work with newer versions of Ansys

Tags: linux, vnc

We have a group of Linux workstations that run various engineering applications. One of these is Ansys. Remote users connect to the workstations using VNC to run the Ansys workbook (GUI) to work on their models, etc. Up through version 19.2 of Ansys, this worked fine. However, with later versions (2020 and newer), the GUI itself will load, but the drawings/models don't appear within the windows.

These are primarily CentOS 7.9 workstations, but I also tried it on Ubuntu 20.04 with the same results. This happens on various VNC clients (RealVNC on Windows, Screen Sharing on Mac).

Comment: What did Ansys customer support say about the issue?